# LinkedIn - blank authorization screen

Tags: php, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm trying to authorize the application, using this link

https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&state=101494cc3b098493d5005aac974b246a1&client_id=XXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.com%2Fwriter%2Flinkedin_callback

but I see a blank dark screen

gyazo.com/ada29b7aa7253f2dba726b347f55456b

when I change something in the URL (for example, remove one letter in the 'state' param) everything becomes well and as it should be

gyazo.com/5e9cdbbadedec22ec6274c1265195c2d

what happening? Is it a bug on their or mine side?